# In php, how do logical operators work _with non-booleans_?

Tags: php, logical-operators

In other programming languages (Python, Ruby, Scheme), I'm used to doing things like

```
$foo = $cat && $dog;
$bar = $fruit || $vegetable;
```

I would expect that $foo would get assigned to $dog if $cat were null, and $bar to $fruit if $fruit were NOT null. I seem to recall getting burned for doing things like this in PHP, and I've never learned exactly how logical operators handle non-boolean operands. Can someone explain or point me in the right direction? I tried reading the following page in the official docs, but it doesn't deal with non-booleans:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: I also read the page on type juggling (http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), and that still didn't clarify the issue for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP the result of a boolean comparison is always a boolean, the operands are coerced to boolean.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

explains which values, when they are coerced, will becomes true or false.

Comment: Thanks, tialaramex. Is it fair to say my first example is equivalent to $foo = ((boolean) $cat) && ((boolean) dog) ?

Comment: I believe this is an accurate characterisation, but I have not tested it extensively so I can't promise there aren't any kinks.

Comment: Where does it say that logical operation expressions always evaluate to a boolean?

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

$foo = $cat ? $cat : $dog;

The first $cat will get turned into a Boolean based on known rules. If it's true then $foo will be $cat otherwise it's $dog.

Comment: @allyourcode Look for the so-called "Elvis operator", then.